# Natural numbers arithmetic property

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have to prove the following $$m < n \iff l + m < l + n$$

by induction with $l, m, n ∈ $ the naturals defined in the von Neumann construction

where $m<n$ is defined as $m$ being strictly a subset of $n$

and where $l+m=s_l(m)$ by the recursion theorem. I have no idea how to start this proof any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show $m<n\iff s(m)<s(n)$?

Comment: No I don't know how you would show that

Comment: what definition do you use for $m<n$. Is it $\exists k\mid n=s_k(m)$

Comment: I stated the definition in the question "where $m<n$ is defined as m being strictly a subset of n"

Comment: Do I fix $m$ and $n$ and do an induction on $l$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $m<n$ be fixed

If $l=0$ then $s_0(m)=m+0=m, s_0(n)=n+0=n$ then certainly $m<n$ so this holds for $l=0$.

Suppose it has been established for some $l \in$ the naturals then:

$$s_l(m')=s_l(m)'<s_l(n)'=s_l(n')$$

Therefore by induction this holds for every $l\in$ the naturals

is this correct?

Comment: By $\alpha',$ do you mean $s_1(\alpha)$?

Comment: By $a'$ I mean it to be defined as the successor of $a$ sorry I should've specified.

Comment: As long as you know that $m<n$ if and only if $m'<n',$ your proof is just fine!